# lsFusion: how to fix a column in a table?

Tags: open-source, lsfusion

Can you please tell me how to fix a column in a table: so that when you move the scrollbar, the column is always visible, for example, the column with the id (I've seen it in MyCompany)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the STICKY keyword when adding a property to a form using [PROPERTIES](https://docs.lsfusion.org/Properties_and_actions_block/). For example :

```
FORM myForm
    OBJECTS o = MyClass
    PROPERTIES(o) STICKY stickyProperty1, stickyProperty2
    PROPERTIES(o)        otherProperty1, otherProperty2
;
```